# Where is DB connection located for JPA using persistence.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, encryption

I was trying to use jasypt to encrypt/decrypt passwords in my persistence.xml but thats not working too good. Sooo.. I figured maybe I can do it myself. My problem is not knowing where the db account is accessed so I can get a handle to it. Here is the password in my persistence.xml:

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="mydbpassword" />
```

This works find and the app connects to the database. When I do a grep of hibernate.connection.password the only hits are the persistence.xml.

Does anyone know where in the code I could get a handle to this to manually decrypt and encrypted password?

thanks!

**UPDATE2 - Got it Working!**
I tried using the JNDI route.  Here are the settings to get it to work:

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="MyApp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/myDB</jta-data-source>
         <properties>
             <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:/myDB" />
```

oracle-ds.xml (in jboss deploy directory)

```
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>/myDB</jndi-name>
        <use-java-context>true</use-java-context>
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=foo.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=myDB)))
        </connection-url>
        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
        <user-name>user1</user-name>
        <password>userpass</password>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should not set the password in your `persistence.xml` but rather doing it over `JNDI` and setting it in the container configuration. That way the password is not stored in your version control and can be only accessed / changed in the container ( tomcat, jboss, websphere & etc ). See [Tomcat JNDI How-To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) for a sample & details

Comment: Got it working! added use-java-context=true in oracle-ds.xml and set the hibernate.connection.datasource in persistence.xml. Maybe only one was needed... but now it works.

Comment: great, glad to help!